# Is there a way to paste something at the end of a line?

Tags: vim

Is there a way to paste something at the end of a line?

Comment: This is slightly better answered on [superuser.com](http://superuser.com/questions/121341/how-can-i-paste-something-at-the-end-of-the-line-in-vim)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move the cursor to the end of the line by pressing `$` then press `p` to paste.